# Shared weights in convolutional autoencoder in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In reading about deconvolution, it is often mentioned to use the transpose of the weights when upsampling, but in the few examples in Tensorflow that I can find, this is not the case. Does the transpose happen internally? Which of the following is correct?

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(matrix, tf.transpose(W1, [1, 0, 2, 3]), ...)

tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(matrix, W1, ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to transpose the weights. It's just a naming convention. 
You can see why they named it the way they did [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/256).  The short summary is that it isn't performing deconvolution and is instead performing a fractionally strided convolution.

Also to answer your question directly the second one is correct.