# Does the tf.nn.conv2d_transpose transpose the filter?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a trained feedforward CNN. The shape of filter is [height, width, in_channels, out_channels]. And i want to use those filter to do deconv, we know that the deconv process needs the transpose of the filter.Do i need to transpose the filter mannuly, or the `TF` will do it inside the `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`and all we need to do is pass the trained filter to `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`?

Answer (score 2):

We needn't to transpose the filter manually.In general, wo organize our code in the following way.

```
stride = [1,1,1,1]
conv1W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal[4,4,3,20])
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, conv1W, strides=stride, padding='SAME')
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
```

Then, do the deconv process

```
deconv1 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv1, conv1W, output_shape=[batch_size,output_height, output_width, output_channels],strides=stride)
res = tf.nn.relu(deconv1)
```

The `res` is the result of deconv process.

In a word, the `filter` and `stride` using in deconv process is the same as the `filter` and `stride` using in conv process.

Comment: I think this should be corrected. I have posted my answer.

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana No, this answer is correct. The conv1 layer will have 20 channels. Those are inputs for the tf.nn.convd_transpose and conv1W needs to have 20 as the last dimension per TF documentation.

See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649775/shared-weights-in-convolutional-autoencoder-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

According to tensorflow documentation, you have to change the filter shape. Here I will put how this fact has described in latest TF documentation 1.9.

For the tf.nn.conv_2d the filter variable should be -  A 4-D tensor of **shape [filter_height, filter_width, *in_channels, out_channels*]**

For the tf.nn.conv_2d_transpose the filter variable should be -  A 4-D tensor of **shape [filter_height, filter_width, *out_channels,in_channels*]**

- Here clearly we can see we need to change the change the shape with respect to out_channels